# Sending files through WCF by MVC (Status 413)

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, http-status-code-413

Hello I am creating simply mvc application to manage files in database.
I am using wcf service with with web.config like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DatabaseContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Database.csdl|res://*/Database.ssdl|res://*/Database.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=localhost;initial catalog=DB;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

    <add name="DBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DatabaseModel.csdl|res://*/DatabaseModel.ssdl|res://*/DatabaseModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=localhost;initial catalog=DB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"
               maxRequestLength="8192"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="TransferService" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" >
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="TransferServiceBehavior" name="WCFServices.DocumentsService" />
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />

        </behavior>
        <behavior name="TransferServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="500" maxConcurrentSessions="500" maxConcurrentInstances="500"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding"   scheme="https" bindingConfiguration="TransferService"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

And there is my webconfig.cfg file from mvc application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="WebApp.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApp-20150429124346;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApp-20150429124346.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"
                 maxRequestLength="8192"/>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers></system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
  <applicationSettings>
    <WebApp.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="WebApp_LoginWebServiceReference_LoginService"
        serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://localhost:47521/LoginService.svc</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="WebApp_PersonWebServiceReference_PersonsService"
        serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://localhost:47521/PersonsService.svc</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="WebApp_CandidateWebServiceReference_CandidatesService"
        serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://localhost:47521/CandidatesService.svc</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="WebApp_DocumentWebServiceReference_DocumentsService"
        serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://localhost:47521/DocumentsService.svc</value>
      </setting>
    </WebApp.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="debug">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IPersonsService"/>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ICandidatesService" />
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IDictionaryService"  />
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IDocumentsService" closeTimeout="04:01:00" openTimeout="04:01:00" receiveTimeout="04:10:00" sendTimeout="04:01:00" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" >
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ILoginService" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:47521/PersonsService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IPersonsService" contract="PersonsServiceReference.IPersonsService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IPersonsService" />
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:47521/CandidatesService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ICandidatesService" contract="CandidatesServiceReference.ICandidatesService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ICandidatesService" />
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:47521/DictionaryService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IDictionaryService" contract="DictionaryServiceReference.IDictionaryService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IDictionaryService" />
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:47521/DocumentsService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IDocumentsService" contract="DocumentServiceReference.IDocumentsService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IDocumentsService" />
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:47521/LoginService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ILoginService" contract="LoginServiceReference.ILoginService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ILoginService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I am getting status code 413 Request Entity Too Large. I dont know what am i missing but i cant cant send file.

Do you see any uncorrect parameters? I just need to send files below 4MB.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: You've got a maxRequestLength of 8K, which is way less than a file size of 4M.  That could easily be the cause.

Comment: i've changed it to 2147483647 in server and client siede, but it doesnt help. I cannot save files of size of 664KB.

Comment: Do you get a different error message post change of the maxRequestLength?

Comment: Error message is the same - "The request failed with HTTP status 413: Request Entity Too Large."
Mayby it affect anything?

Comment: take a look at this : http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2328/413-request-entity-too-large-error-with-uploading-a-file

Comment: I tried it but it doesnt help me at all. Still the same error code. I am using IIS Express.